# Need to hide initial div after dropping

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I've managed to get a div to drop within the bounds of another div, then have it become draggable. However the initial div remains. How would I go about hiding or removing it?

HTML:

```
<html><body>
<div class="dragImg">
<img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2008/06/04/article-0-0179864B00000578-284_224x423.jpg" width="50" height="94" class="img"></div>
</div>
<div id="dropHere"></div>
</body></html>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){  
 //Make every clone image unique.   

var counts = [0];
    var resizeOpts = { 
      handles: "none" ,autoHide:true
    };    
   $(".dragImg").draggable({
                         helper: "clone",
                         //Create counter
                         start: function() { counts[0]++; }
                        });

$("#dropHere").droppable({
       drop: function(e, ui){
               if(ui.draggable.hasClass("dragImg")) {
     $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
   //Pointing to the dragImg class in dropHere and add new class.
         $("#dropHere .dragImg").addClass("item-"+counts[0]);
            $("#dropHere .img").addClass("imgSize-"+counts[0]);

   //Remove the current class (ui-draggable and dragImg)
         $("#dropHere .item-"+counts[0]).removeClass("dragImg ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging");

$(".item-"+counts[0]).dblclick(function() {
$(this).remove();
});     
    make_draggable($(".item-"+counts[0])); 
      $(".imgSize-"+counts[0]).resizable(resizeOpts);     
       }

       }
      });

var zIndex = 0;
function make_draggable(elements)
{   
    elements.draggable({
        containment:'parent',
        start:function(e,ui){ ui.helper.css('z-index',++zIndex); },
        stop:function(e,ui){
        }
    });

}


});

</script>
```

Here's my JFiddle for full code and demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2rxC4/6/

Comment: you want only one div?

Comment: Jsut gave an id to the div and then remove it in the drop event http://jsfiddle.net/2rxC4/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your initial image div an ID, such as "initialDragImg":

```
<html><body>
<div class="dragImg" id="initialDragImg">
<img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2008/06/04/article-0-0179864B00000578-    284_224x423.jpg" width="50" height="94" class="img"></div>
</div>
<div id="dropHere"></div>
</body></html>
```

And then in your JQuery, when you drop the image into the draggable area, use this:

```
$("#initialDragImg").hide();
```

When you double click to remove the image from the draggable area, you can show the initial image again if you want, by adding:

```
$("#dragImgInitial").show();
```

into the code where you remove the image from the draggable div.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rxC4/12/)

Ofcourse, if you don't want to re-show the image when you remove it from the draggable div, simply change the call to hide the "initialDragImg" div, to remove it instead:

```
$("#initialDragImg").remove();
```

**UPDATE:**

Following on the new change to support multiple images:

Add the following into the drop function:

```
$("#dropHere .dragImg").attr("originalid", ui.draggable.eq(0).attr("id"));
```

This adds the ID of the dropped div to the clone present in the draggable area. This will allow us to find the original div we hid, to reshow when we remove the image.

Next, add the following into the double click function, for re-showing the original image to the side:

```
$("#" + $(this).attr("originalid")).show();
```

This finds the original div using the "originalid" attribute on the image we just double clicked.

See the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rxC4/31/) for the working solution.

Comment: So I've introduced a second image, since the practical use of this application might have up to 20 different images I need to drag. In the javascript how can I detect which image's id has been dragged? I know how to parse values in old js, but not sure how to do it with jquery. The latest JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/2rxC4/17/

Comment: Updated answer :) that should work no matter how many images you add.

Comment: That's perfect - I've just tried it with 16 images and it works brilliantly. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

remove the helper method,

```
   $(".dragImg").draggable({

                     //Create counter
                     start: function() { counts[0]++; }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the helper from `clone` to `original`

```
$(".dragImg").draggable({
                         helper: "original",
                         //Create counter
                         start: function() { counts[0]++; }
                        });
```

and then edit this line here

```
$(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
```

to

```
$(this).append($(ui.helper));
```